# How do I keep auto-generated columns in PostgreSQL even after removing the source columns?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a table that has autogenerated columns:

```
--  function that creates GEOGRAPHY point from given inputs
create or replace 
function create_point_geography (long DOUBLE PRECISION, lat DOUBLE PRECISION)
  returns GEOGRAPHY
  language sql 
  immutable 
as $$
  select ST_GeogFromText(CONCAT('SRID=4326;POINT(', long::text, ' ', lat::text, ')'))
$$;


CREATE TABLE driver_orders (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  driver_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  address_from VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  address_to VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  active BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
  date DATE NOT NULL,
  longitude_from DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL, -- want to omit
  latitude_from DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,  -- want to omit
  longitude_to DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,   -- want to omit
  latitude_to DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,    -- want to omit
  -- add autogenerated 'location_from' column
  location_from GEOGRAPHY
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    (create_point_geography(longitude_from, latitude_from))
      stored,
  -- add autogenerated 'location_to' column
  location_to GEOGRAPHY
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    (create_point_geography(longitude_to, latitude_to))
      stored
);
```

As you can see 2 columns are autogenerated based on values of other columns. I want to remove the columns named `longitude_from, latitude_from, longitude_to, latitude_to` whose values are used in generator function. But I want to keep auto-nenerated columns. So, basically I want  columns `location_from, location_to` be auto-generated with given values, not based on other columns.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO! You cannot do what you want - at least directly. The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) clearly indicates this:

> A generated column is a special column that is **always computed from
> other columns**.

You can however get the results by making the conversion to a GEOGRAPHY column during the `insert` by calling the same function.

```
create table driver_orders (
  id            serial primary key,
  driver_id     integer not null,
  address_from  varchar not null,
  address_to    varchar not null,
  active        boolean default true,
  date          date    not null,
  location_from geography not null,
  location_to   geography not null
);

insert into driver_orders(location_from, location_to , ...) 
     select create_point_geography(longitude_from, latitude_from)
          , create_point_geography(longitude_to, latitude_to)
          , ... 
          );
```

Comment: While this works, I suspect the OP would be better served by creating an INSERT trigger to put values in the columns, so that the INSERT statement doesn't know about the generated columns.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, I guess that is a matter of philosophy, but I disagree. Putting the function call in a trigger is of course completely valid. However, I  preferred putting it  directly in the INSERT. In the statement it is completely clear what is happening while a trigger hides what is happening.  I want the INSERT to know what it does, and more importantly the developers that follow. Again, matter of philosophy.